# Python / Django - Accept payements ? Seed storage?

Tags: new-developer, python-sdk, seed

Tried to search over github for a readymade Django Stellar Package, is there any available or do I have to start from scratch using the Python SDK ?

How to safely store the seed/mnemonic for a public facing webserver ?

Edit: You you look at the linked tutorial below http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/develop-your-first-python-app-integrated-with-decentralized-stellar-network/

> In the **main** of your Flask app assign these addresses to some variables, I do as below:
>
> ```
> SITE_ADDR = 'GAFNKWN2GX7FCCSYLS36OUN2NIWJAU4UVZC44MVTQQX6HDAUZ2UUQL6I'
> SITE_SEED = 'SCC2V25EPMDLWUXNOJNLTBFXMWDHLLNJOY4DN5LWIEKFMYADNPW2OFXX'
> MEMBER_ADD = 'GBYVSIXRDKJDHY5JGK6N37RFLZ2JDH3GDZPYOWXITQCWOCQ26VSRSXZF'
> MEMBER_SEED = 'SBGUJJV6FSUL5S3AWH36XPYFIGGMAV3RQK7NSZWO7PTIS2ZCSPFVREGT'
> ```

That's exactly my concern, if by any chance my main.py is leaked. Everything is compromised.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are no stellar-django packages.

Not sure what you mean here by "seed" but user data shouldn't be stored on any public facing endpoints/public facing endpoints. I think the answer you may be looking for is try implementing in browser signing instead.